# g.addV().property(T.label, "SomeLabel") vs g.addV("SomeLabel")

Tags: java, gremlin, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune

I'm a bit new to gremlin and graph db's in general. I'm a bit confused by these two methods which appear to be doing the same thing but the syntax is different.
Plus one of these works when I'm using Gremlin Server while the other gives me an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two bits of Gremlin are identical, the first is the just the long hand form. If I recall the history correctly, `g.addV(String)` was added to provide symmetry with `addE(String)`. You should not be getting an error on either method, but you should prefer the `addV(String)`.